Can this locus be an ellipse?

Let $A=(-1,0)$ and $B=(2,0)$ be two points on the $x-$ axis. A point $M$ is moving in the xy-plane in such a way that $\angle MBA=2\angle MAB.$ Find the locus of $M$.

My Attempt:
$\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$
$\left|\frac k{h-2}\right|=\frac{2\left|\frac k{h+1}\right|}{1-\left(\frac k{h+1}\right)^2}$
With plus sign, I am getting
$(h-2)^2+k^2=7$
With minus sign, I am getting
$3h^2-k^2=3$
But the answer given is only hyperbola.
Maybe plus sign is rejected while taking slope or angle orientation. Not sure. What do you think?

Could you explain what $h$ and $k$ are?

@DuongNgo $M\equiv(h,k)$

While dealing with such questions where we have to establish relations between slopes of lines based on angles between them, it must be kept in mind that while using the formula for the acute angle between $2$ lines in equations
$$\tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$
the absolute value must be opened with $+$ if $\theta$ is measured anti-clockwise and $-$ if $\theta$ is measured clockwise or $+$ if $\theta$ is measured clockwise and $-$ if $\theta$ is measured clockwise. That is, for opening the absolute values for the tangents of $2$ angles with the same sign, the angles must be measured in the same sense.
In your question, it is clear that $\angle MAB$ is anti-clockwise when measured from $AB$ to $AM$ ands $\angle MBA$ is anti-clockwise when measured from $BM$ to $BA$. This means that the locus of $M(h,k)$ will be given by
$$\frac{-k}{h-2}=\frac{2\frac k{h+1}}{1-\left(\frac k{h+1}\right)^2}$$
This explains why the $+$ sign is rejected and only the $-$ sign is considered.
